# Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk from Visual studio code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know it's possible to deploy a .net core application to elastic beanstalk via visual studio as shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-beanstalk-traditional.html

But is it possible to deploy a .net core application to elastic beanstalk via **Visual Studio Code**?

Current OS: mac

Answer (score 3):

After some further digging it seems that the only way to deploy to beanstalk on a macOS will be through the elastic beanstalk CLI. Setup instructions can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-advanced.html

You'd need to install python in order to get pip just incase anyone misses that.